# Use different date as UNIX epoch time in Java?

Tags: java

I know that the standard UNIX epoch time is 1/1/70 and I can use this variable to convert current time to UNIX time:

int time = (int) ((System.currentTimeMillis())/1000);

(Note: I know it's normally stored as a 64-bit long but I need it to be 32 bit, hence the cast to int).

My question is - are there any built-in methods in Java where you can pass in a different date as the "epoch date." What I am trying to get is a timestamp in # of seconds since a particular date. I.e. I would like to define January 1, 2015 as MY epoch. And then each future date would be # of seconds since 1/1/2015.

If there's no Java library that provides that capability, any ideas on how to do this?
Thanks,
Tim

Comment: There is no way in the standard library to set the epoch date and time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no library needed, you just have to use maths.

```
static final SimpleDateFormat SDF = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
static final long EPOCH = new Date(2015 - 1900, Calendar.JANUARY, 1).getTime(); // 2015/1/1 in GMT

public static int secondSinceEpoch() {
    return (int) ((System.currentTimeMillis() - EPOCH) / 1000);
}

public static String epochToString(int secsSince2015) {
    return SDF.format(new Date(secsSince2015 * 1000 + EPOCH));
}

public static void main(String... ignored) {
    System.out.println(new Date(EPOCH));
    System.out.println("Epoch is " + epochToString(0));
    System.out.println("Today is " + secondSinceEpoch() + " secs");
    System.out.println("Today is " + secondSinceEpoch() / 86400 + " days");
}
```

prints

```
Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT 2015
Epoch is 2015/01/01 00:00:00
Today is -15732850 secs
Today is -182 days
```

Comment: Thanks. I can't declare that static variable as it causes a "Unhandled exception type ParseException" error.

Comment: You can handle exceptions in a static block but easier to use new Date()

Comment: Thanks. With that code, I'm getting a number like -18442006. What does that number represent though? Effectively, since 1/1/1970 = 0 in UNIX epoch time, I really just want 1/1/2015 = 0 for my epoch time. So, if I were to look at sometime today, I would get something like -15724800 (i.e. 60*60*24*182).

Comment: @user3712321 for Date the first month is 0.  Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably have to roll your own time and date methods, which would basically repackage the standard ones while subtracting the correct number of seconds to the epoch to arrive at your new epoch.

So, maybe something like

```
public class MyEpoch {
    public static final Long MY_EPOCH = //number of seconds betweer 1/1/70 and 1/1/2015
    private Date unixEpochDate;
    //etc
    public Long getMyEpoch() {
        return unixEpochDate.getTime() - MY_EPOCH;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
long totalSeconds = Duration.between ( OffsetDateTime.of ( 2015 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , ZoneOffset.UTC ) , OffsetDateTime.now ( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ).getSeconds ();
```

## Elapsed time

Forget about the [epoch reference date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)). What you want is simply elapsed time.

## java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the old troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`. The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) team also advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to Android in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

## Time zone

Your question fails to address the crucial issue of time zone.

Since you mentioned Unix-style time, I will assume you intended UTC time zone. The [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in UTC with a resolution up to nanosecond. For more flexibility including formatting, use an `OffsetDateTime` with an assigned offset of UTC instead.

## `Duration`

The `OffsetDateTime` class represents a date and time-of-day with an assigned offset-from-UTC. We can specify the constant `ZoneOffset.UTC` as the offset value.

The `Duration` class represents a span of time as a total number of seconds plus a fractional second in nanoseconds. We can get a `Duration` object from our pair of `OffsetDateTime` objects.

Calling [`Duration::getSeconds`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#getSeconds--) gets the total number of seconds in the duration. But note that we may be losing data as any fractional second will naturally be omitted from the resulting number.

```
OffsetDateTime start = OffsetDateTime.of ( 2015 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , ZoneOffset.UTC );
OffsetDateTime now = OffsetDateTime.now ( ZoneOffset.UTC );

Duration duration = Duration.between ( start , now );
long totalSeconds = duration.getSeconds ();
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "start: " + start + " | now: " + now + " | duration: " + duration + " | totalSeconds: " + totalSeconds );
```

> start: 2015-01-01T00:00Z | now: 2016-07-24T04:15:57.345Z | duration: PT13684H15M57.345S | totalSeconds: 49263357

Going the other direction, calculating a date-time from your starting point with a number of seconds, is easy. Just call `plusSeconds`.

Rather than dirty your code with “magic” numbers and math calculations to get a number of seconds, use the [`TimeUnit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) class.

```
OffsetDateTime start = OffsetDateTime.of ( 2015 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , ZoneOffset.UTC );
long seconds = TimeUnit.HOURS.toSeconds ( 7 );  // Let `TimeUnit` class do the math of calculating seconds.
OffsetDateTime stop = start.plusSeconds ( seconds );
```

> 2015-01-01T07:00Z